# Spring mvc controller return Collection(set, list), jsp use it as array

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

In controller:

```
return model.addAttribute("test", new Set<test>());
```

In JSP, could use jstl

```
<c:forEach items="${test}" var=value>
```

to get value from Set.

Is it any way to convert Set to array **In JSP**? Instead of using jstl , we use like `test[0]`, `test[1]` ... to access Set value.

Answer (score 1):

- `set.toArray()` will convert it to array
- you can use jstl `<c:forEach>` with either array or a set
- by definition a set is not indexed, so you can't obtain elements by index, you can just iterate it

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Yes for ur first approach using set.toArray(). can i do it in JSP and get array directly?